# JavaScript Cookout.js

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, assuming that hot dogs come in packages of 10, and hot dog buns come in packages of 8. Write a program called cookout.js, that calculates the number of packages of hot dogs and the number of packages of hot dog buns needed for a cookout, with the minimum amount of leftovers. The program should assume there will be 525 people attending the cookout and each person will eat 3 hot dogs. The program should display the following details.The minimum number of packages of hot dogs required.  The minimum number of packages of hot dog buns required.  The number of hot dogs that will be left over.  The number of hot dog buns that will be left over.

I have tried every possible resource and I just can't understand why I can't get this. Please help me.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: var multiply = function(p,s) {
 return p * s;
};
multiply(525,3)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO isn't a "write this code for me" service.

Comment: I was asking for help. It's not off-topic. As you can see, I had some of the code written. Granted part of it was wrong but thats how you learn. And I reread my chapter twice, went to a tutor, researched, and watched Lynda.com videos for assistance in addition to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because who needs homework, right? It doesn't help you learn or anything.

```
var totalHotdogs = 525 * 3;
console.log('Total hotdog packs: ' + Math.ceil(totalHotdogs / 10));
console.log('Hotdogs remaining: ' + totalHotdogs % 10);
console.log('Total bun packs: ' + Math.ceil(totalHotdogs / 8));
console.log('Buns remaining: ' + totalHotdogs % 8);
```

Comment: Okay, so this is what it should look like all together?var multiply = function(p,s) {
 return p * s;
};
multiply(525,3)

var totalHotdogs = 525 * 3;
console.log('Total hotdog packs: ' + Math.ceil(totalHotdogs / 10));
console.log('Hotdogs remaining: ' + totalHotdogs % 10);
console.log('Total bun packs: ' + Math.ceil(totalHotdogs / 8));
console.log('Buns remaining: ' + totalHotdogs % 8);

Comment: just say `var totalHotdogs = multiply(525, 3)`. No need for the actual inline multiplication now, because the function already exists